# Maven install and deploy shows SUCCESS when tests throw runtime exception

Tags: maven, installation, deployment, continuous-integration, maven-surefire-plugin

Maven install and deploy shows SUCCESS even when tests throw exception for loading application context. Shows fialure: 0. How do I make my install and deploy fail in these cases.

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>sqlite4java.library.path</name>
                            <value>${project.build.directory}/lib</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <version>${maven-deploy-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <preparationGoals>clean</preparationGoals>
                    <arguments>-s settings.xml</arguments>
                    <goals>clean deploy</goals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Why have you defined the deploy plugin with `<phase>none</phase>`? That's simply wrong...Furthermore defining `<goals>clean deploy</goals>` for maven-release-plugin. The `clean` is useless because during a release the code will be checkout fresh into `target/checkout` there is no need for `clean`...and why do you use `-s settings.xml`? Do you have a `settings.xml` checked in? How do you call your build?

Comment: I have a settings.xml that I have checked in. Locally if I run  mvn clean install -s settings.xml -Dspring.profiles.active=local,test,live-ticket, it passes but I can the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)`.    I understand why the error is showing but I don't understand why the output is not marked as FAILED. It's marked as SUCCESS.

Comment: The Junit test when run from IDE shows as failure though.

Comment: Why do you have `settings.xml` checked in. Does not make sense. The first thing you have to cleanup your test to get them working. Second if you run integration tests (via maven-failsafe-plugin) you have to do the checking for integration tests see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html (the verify part)...which I don't see anywhere in your pom excerpts...

Comment: My question is more regarding unit test. Why an exception during unit test wont fail my mvn install locally ?

Comment: You are not running unit tests because otherwise the build would have failed...or you are giving command line options to ignore failures... what I don't know but already asked to answer...